# Visual Studio WSDL import

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to import a wsdl file and generate the proxy in C# where the namespace contains the following "urn://...". However I get the error The string 'urn://...' is not a valid Uri value.. If I remove this // I can import but I can not make the calls. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem (The WSDL owner can not change this urn). If it is not possible how can I make SOAP call without importing the WSDL and if it is safe to do this? (I'm using C#/VS 2017)

Comment: I've never seen a urn with a format like `usr://`.  You may want to read the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2141.  I've used `urn:` URNs many times without any issue.

Comment: Me too, but the owner showed me other applications that are consuming their webservices with this urn

Answer (score 0):

The given namespace is invalid. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141#section-2.2
It states that the "/" character is a reserved character in rfc1630 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630)

Owner should consider correcting this...